# Grails nullable overrides my validator

Tags: validation, grails

I have a domain class in witch i want a constraint to have a cutom validation message.

```
tyyp validator:{val,obj -> if(val == null) return ['type.missing', obj.(otherclass).field]}
```

Problem ise that nullable thati  have not specified here overrides my validator. My validator is never called. if i set nullable:true then i still get some other message not my own. What am i doing wrong ?

The same issue comes both on saving the instance of class and if i do domain.addToMyClasses(mydomainclass)

Neither will use my validator.

EDIT1
Solved the issue. Problem was that grails documendation said that if in language file i have written it in form of package.package....classname.fieldname.type.missing then i can just use 'type.missing', but actually i have to use the full name. Because this was wrong it didnt find the string and just passed over it with a default message.

Comment: What is this, `obj.(otherclass).field`?

Comment: String. But i fixed it. Grails documentation was not clear enough. 'type.missing' has to be full length. 'pathtoclass.class.type.missing', this fixed it.

Comment: Are you pointing to a h2 database, or a persistent databases as mysql?